# Adding a circle to a vector source in Open Layers 3

Tags: javascript, coordinates, geometry, layer, openlayers-3

My code goes like this:

```
var circle = new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 5,
                fill: null,
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.9)',
                    width: 3
                })
            });
var circleFeature = new ol.Feature(circle);
```

I have tried

```
circle.setCoordinates([x,y]);
```

and

```
circleFeature.setCoordinates([x,y]);
```

But each time I get

> Object doesn't support property or method 'setCoordinates'.

I guess I am not applying setCoordinates to the right object. The example code from or own application that I need to replicate with a Circl simply has a LineString instead of a Circle, but I don't find how to use it with a Circle so far.

Comment: It looks like one of the problems I have is that I am using ol.style.Circle instead of ol.geom.Circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
var circle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 5,
        fill: null,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.9)',
            width: 3
        })
    })
});

var feature = new ol.Feature(
    new ol.geom.Point([0, 0])
);
feature.setStyle(circle);
vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
```

So, you apply a style to the feature and if you want to setCoordinates you can use:

```
feature.getGeometry().setCoordinates(coordinate);
```

[A Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/sz95add7/).